# How do I patch a deeply buried method on an object that never explicitly exists in the test file?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

Here is a portion of my test file:

```
@pytest.fixture
def live_sftp():

    sftp = SFTP(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD)

    # add some directories and files

    yield sftp

    # Cleanup after test

@pytest.mark.parametrize('kwargs,expected', args_and_expected['get_files'])
@patch('<my_code>.sftp.sftp.paramiko.sftp_client.FTPClient.get')
def test_get_files(mock_get, kwargs, expected, live_sftp):
    results = sorted(live_sftp.get_files(**kwargs))
    assert mock_get.call_count == len(results)
    assert_results_match_expected(expected, results)
```

I'm testing a method called `get_files` that eventually calls `get_file`. Here's an abbreviated version of the class I'm testing:

```
class SFTP(object):
   
    def __init__(self, host, username, password, port=22, rsa_private_key_file=None):
        # do stuff

    @contextmanager
    def create_connection(self):
        transport = <do stuff to define transport>
        conn = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
        yield conn
        conn.close()
        transport.close()

    def get_file(self, remote_path, local_path=None, connection=None):

        if not local_path:
            local_path = files.create_temp_file_for_path(remote_path)

        if connection:
            connection.get(remote_path, local_path)
        with self.create_connection() as connection:
            connection.get(remote_path, local_path)

        return local_path

    def get_files(<kwargs>):
        # this is a pseudocode version of get_files
        paths = []
        files = <stuff to generate list of files>
        for file in files:
            paths.append(self.get_file(file))
        return paths
```

`connection` is an instance of [this class](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient), which I'm not sure I'm referring to correctly in my patch.  That `get` is what I want to patch.

An abbreviated version of my directory structure is:

```
├── <my_code>
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── sftp
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── sftp.py
│   │   └── utilities.py
├── pytest.ini
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── fixtures.py
│   ├── test_sftp.py
```

My test fails with  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<my_code>.sftp.sftp.paramiko'; '<my_code.sftp.sftp' is not a package`.  That makes sense; `'<my_code>.sftp.sftp'` isn't a package; it's a module. But I've read the docs and several other Stack Overflow questions and I can't find an example that illustrates what I want to do; nor can I extrapolate it from what I understand (maybe not much) of the underlying principles.

Maybe the confusing issue is that the only relevant import the test file does is `from <my-code>.sftp import SFTP`.  Instances of the `SFTP` class yield a `connection` when they're told to create one, and there's no access to this `get` method other than through `connection`.

In my test file, an instance of `SFTP` is yielded by a fixture.  So maybe my problem is that I can only patch something that exists relative to an imported object in my test file, and the only thing that has that get method in my test file doesn't exist till it's yielded.  It never exists explicitly in the test file.  Is there a way to patch `connection.get`/`paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get` given that neither of these entities ever exist in the test file?

Edit history: I realized I made some misleading and wrong statements about my test file; I have corrected them. I also deleted a proposed solution I was considering that only made sense given my previous misleading and wrong statements.  In yet another edit, I moved code in my question around for clarity.

A possible solution on further thought while making all my edits: In my fixture, I explicitly overwrite `create_connection`.  It's identical except that it after creating `conn` and before yielding it, it sets `conn.get` to a Mock.  The fixture function would have to return both `sftp` and `conn.get` for my tests to have access to it. Since not every test should mock `conn.get`, I have two options: make two different fixtures, or turn the fixture into a function that takes a `do_mock` Boolean, and returns a function that in turn would return `(sftp, conn.get)`. This second option would add a line of code to every test.  If anyone can suggest anything less complicated than this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: if you are testing `get_files` you should be patching `get_file`. that is the whole point of the unit test, the test is supposed to test _how_ `get_files` works, not how `get_file` works within the context of that function

Comment: The problem, which is maybe dealwithable, is that if I patch get_file, I have to find a way to give the get_file mock a different return value on every call to it (one of its arguments). I can do this by subclassing MagicMock and creating a method that sets the return value to this argument, but it didn't seem obviously better/less complicated to me than trying to surgically Mock the thing I wanted to stop from happening -- the actual download.  Maybe it is.

Comment: then mock this `paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport`, because that is where the connection is coming from, in which case any call to `get` will do nothing

Comment: Not trying to be difficult here, but: what problem does that solve, either practically or in principle, over mocking just 'get'?  It has all the same technical issues, in that I'm mocking something that's never imported into my test file.  I had already decided I was going to create another SFTP fixture that explicitly overwrites create_connection with a version of the method that's identical but for making `conn.get` a mock.  The same thing is necessary for patching the whole connection object (comment continues...).

Comment: Further, I actually do want to set up a remote file system for SFTP that the files really do access, which becomes a problem if I mock the whole connection.  I just don't want to actually download the files, and to have to give the test a location on the local file system I'm sure it can write to, and to deal with cleanup.  Nor do I want to just test get_files with the temp files option -- that means I can't test the various things that are supposed to happen when you pass get_files specific local paths, it's probably file system dependent what the returned temp files would look like, etc.